# No me funciona el balanceo de pila

Tags: java, pilas

Esoy haciendo un programa de balanceo de pila, ejecuto el programa pero no pasa nada,el tiempo de ejecución es de 0 segundos, ¿me podrían decir en que me equivoco?, este es el codigo:

```
package bracket.checker;

import java.util.Stack;

/**
 *
 * @author Usuario
 */
public class BracketChecker {

    private String expresion;

    public  BracketChecker(String e){
        this.expresion=e;
    }

    public boolean esValido(){
    Stack pila =new Stack();    

    for(int i = 0; i<expresion.length();i++){
        if(expresion.charAt(i)=='('){
            pila.push('(');
        }
        if(expresion.charAt(i)== ')'){

            if(pila.empty() ){
                pila.push(')');
            }else{
                pila.pop();
            }


        }
        if(expresion.charAt(i)=='{'){
            pila.push('{');
        }
        if(expresion.charAt(i)== '}'){

            if(pila.empty() ){
                pila.push('}');
            }else{
                pila.pop();
            }
        }

        if(expresion.charAt(i)=='['){
            pila.push('[');
        }
          if(expresion.charAt(i)== '['){

            if(pila.empty() ){
                pila.push('[');
            }else{
                pila.pop();
            }
        }

    }
        if(pila.empty()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
       String e1= "{([])}";
       String e2= "(][])";
       String e3= "[]{()}";

        BracketChecker parentesis = new BracketChecker(e1);
        parentesis.esValido();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola Bruno, bienvenido. Deberías añadir mensajes de log en las funciones para ir *viendo* la traza y ejecución del programa. Te será mas facil entender donde entra y por qué. Un saludo

Comment: quizas seria bueno que explicara por que no le funciona como espera pues usted dice que no le funciona por *...no pasa nada,el tiempo de ejecución es de 0 segundos...* quizas este tardando 0.05 segundos, no se si eso que comenta es base para decir que no le funciona, el programa compila y @Monclus le comenta una posible causa de comportamiento inesperado, podria añadir el comportamiento que esta teniendo y cual es el esperado. Saludos

Comment: Si, disculpen... lo que pasa es que me debe devolver true o false si es que la pila esta vacia o llena respectivamente, ya que con la pila voy viendo si esque el string ingresado esta equilibrado en sus parentesis(cuando hay un prentesis que sobra se agrega a la pila).

Comment: ¿Has hecho un `println(parentesis.esValido())` o algo por el estilo para comprobar que valor te devuelve?

Comment: contando con lo que comenta @Monclus lo que veo es que usted mete y saca sin tener encuenta si realmente es uno la pareja del otro por ejemplo: `String e1= "{([][))}";`  fijese en esta parte -> `[ )` y el retorna true, quizas tenga que chequear si se encuentra la pareja antes de sacarlo de la pila. Saludos

Comment: Mil disculpas debe ser la hora pero ya se porque no me mostraba los valores jajaja gracias a todos por ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Si no he entendido mal el codigo un posible error podría estar en esta parte:

```
if(expresion.charAt(i)=='['){
    pila.push('[');
}
if(expresion.charAt(i)== '['){
    if(pila.empty() ){
        pila.push('[');
    }else{
        pila.pop();
    }
}
```

Ya que siempre se hace el if comparando con `'['`, supongo que del copy/paste se te ha olvidado cambiarlo por `']'`.

Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo!